# Tectonic Trouble

Tags: cryptic-clues

I once lived in California, and recently a friend called me. He missed me, as I was working, but he left this on my answering machine:

> An earthquake shook most of the saints, except for the last one. The first two droughts marked the beginning of the end, but we still took literally as long as possible to respond. Poetic?

I'm not at all sure what he was trying to say, can someone help me solve this?

EDIT: I forgot to mention this originally, but the next day I got a letter from him that simply said this:

> (7)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SECOND TRY - WITH FAULTY EXPLANATION
```

An answer -  which may be poetic?

> ANDREAS, there is an Old English epic poem on the life of [St. Andrew the Apostle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andreas_(poem))

An earthquake shook most of the saints, except for the last one.

> The California setting, suggests the *San Andreas Fault*, which causes earthquakes in a state with many cities named after saints (San/Santa). The first **An** is literal and I'm unable to explain.

The first two droughts marked the beginning of the end,

> The first two *dr*oughts → **dr**
>  marked: a connector
>  the beginning of the *e*nd → **e**

but we still took literally as long as possible to respond.

> but we still took: a connector
>  literally *as* → **as**
>  long as possible to respond → fluff

These give the message

> **Andreas** (7). If someone can solve this pls post - also attempted to fit *Address* and failed.

```
FIRST FAR OFF ATTEMPT
```

An earthquake shook most of the saints, except for the last one.

> **saint** - all but the last of saints is going to be shook or anagrammed.

The first two droughts marked the beginning of the end,

> first **t**wo **d**roughts give the beginning/end of the word,

but we still took literally as long as possible to respond.

> remotely suggests that this message from your friend is a reminder that you are:   **distant** (7).

Poetic?

> Yes, poetic licence was taken.

Comment: unfortunately not the answer, but nice try :)

Comment: Second try is correct, nice job.